# MySql query for displaying rows as column dyanmically

Tags: mysql, sql

I've to join three tables the resultant output will be like this

```
+---------------+--------------+-------------+-------------+
| Category_Name | English      | French      | German      |
+---------------+--------------+-------------+-------------+
| Clothing      | english_name | french_name | german_name |
| Electronics   | NULL         | NULL        | NULL        |
| Ornaments     | NULL         | NULL        | NULL        |
+---------------+--------------+-------------+-------------+
```

Following is my table_structure

```
tbl_category
+----+---------------+
| id | category_name |
+----+---------------+
| 1  | Clothing      |
| 2  | Electronics   |
| 3  | Ornaments     |
+----+---------------+

tbl_languages
+----+----------+
| id | language |
+----+----------+
| 1  | English  |
| 2  | French   |
| 3  | German   |
+----+----------+

tbl_languages_data

+----+-------------+-------------+---------------+
| id | language_id | category_id | category_name |
+----+-------------+-------------+---------------+
| 1  | 1           | 1           | english_name  |
| 2  | 2           | 1           | french_name   |
| 3  | 3           | 1           | german_name   |
+----+-------------+-------------+---------------+
```

I've two questions.
1. Are these relations are valid or there can be some other way to avoid deadlocks
2. What will be the query for getting this result.

**Note:** The output should be **dynamic** as I've to add more data to `tbl_language`.

Answer (score 0):

Should be something along the lines of:

```
SELECT Category_Name
        MAX(CASE when lan.language_id = 1 THEN lan.category_name END) as 'English',
        MAX(CASE when lan.language_id = 2 THEN lan.category_name END) as 'French',
        MAX(CASE when lan.language_id = 3 THEN lan.category_name END) as 'German'
FROM tbl_category cat
RIGHT JOIN tbl_languages_data lan ON cat.id = lan.category_id
GROUP BY Category_Name
```

NOTE: Did not notice your edit, I don't think you will be able to dynamically add columns to the expected result. Please somebody correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score -1):

I would omit the last column *Category Name* from *tbl_languages_data*. And refer the Language_id as an number, this way you will compare the two indexes with the same datatype (*int* to *int*). This will be faster than a *string* with an *int*. This will result in the following query:

```
SELECT  cat.category_name
,       lang.language
FROM    tbl_category AS cat
LEFT JOIN tbl_languages_data AS lang_data
        ON lang_data.category_id = cat.id
LEFT JOIN tbl_languages AS lang
        ON lang_data.language_id = lang.id
```

Note that this is different than your expected result set. The three languages are now translated into one column. And here is your table design:

```
 tbl_category
+----+---------------+
| id | category_name |
+----+---------------+
| 1  | Clothing      |
+----+---------------+
| 2  | Electronics   |
+----+---------------+
| 3  | Ornaments     |
+----+---------------+

tbl_languages
+----+----------+
| id | language |
+----+----------+
| 1  | English  |
+----+----------+
| 2  | French   |
+----+----------+
| 3  | German   |
+----+----------+

tbl_languages_data

+----+-------------+-------------+
| id | language_id | category_id | 
+----+-------------+-------------+
| 1  | 1           | 1           | 
+----+-------------+-------------+
| 2  | 2           | 1           | 
+----+-------------+-------------+
| 3  | 3           | 1           | 
+----+-------------+-------------+
```

Comment: I don't understand why my answer is now -1. If you add *ON UPDATE CASCADE* as a foreign key constraint on your column *language_id* than that id is automatically incremented once you insert another language in **tbl_languages**